# Delete the previous image in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

An image is populated correctly when I click the value.

When I click on the image, the **previous image** has to be deleted.

I tried a delete code.

```vb
Private Sub ShowValues()
Dim a As String
Dim Var As String
Dim Var2 As String
Dim insert_path As String
Dim pic As Picture

'Delete Code
For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, Range("H10:R24")) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next pic

Range("C1").Value = ActiveCell.Value
'a = Range("C1").Value
Var = "********" 'drivepath
'MsgBox (Range("B" & j).Value)
Var2 = Range("C1").Value
insert_path = Var & "\" & Var2

Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(insert_path, _
  msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 400, 160, 800, 600)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you run the routine several times, and if it runs the 2nd time you want to delete the picture that was added when it was executed the first time?

Comment: Btw: Why do you tag the question with MacOS? Using a backslash suggest that the code runs on Windows.

Comment: @FunThomas yeah
Btw, its macros will edit it

Comment: Have a closer look to the tags you are using. The tag for "Macros" explicitly states **`"*** DO NOT USE FOR VBA***"`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several ways to identify a shape. Problem by identify it by the cell Range or it's Top/Left property is that this might change if the user moves the image around or resize some cells, so at the end of the day this is not reliable.

I would suggest you name the shape holding the picture after inserting it. Now before you insert it, check if there is already a shape with that name and remove it (I took the freedom to rename your variables):

```
Private Sub ShowValues()
    Const imageShapeName = "MyGreatShapeHoldingAnImage"  ' Whatever you want.
    
    Dim path As String, imageName As String, fullName As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("C1").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        path = "********" 'drivepath
        imageName = Range("C1").Value
        fullName = path & "\" & imageName
    
        Dim pic As Shape
        On Error Resume Next
        Set pic = .Shapes(imageShapeName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not pic Is Nothing Then pic.Delete
    
        Call .Shapes.AddPicture(fullName, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 400, 160, 800, 600)
        Set pic = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        pic.Name = imageShapeName
    End With
End Sub
```